# How to merge only specific text parts of two columns into one column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two columns in a pandas dataframe with 1000 rows. The difficulty I am having is merging only a specific part of the text. For example:

This is what I have, two columns:

```
Col1            Col2
11.50.199.1     12121.0
12.55.222.1     12121.0
```

What I want is to merge the two columns so that the the example above becomes this:

```
ColNew
11.50.199.12121
12.55.222.12121
```

I want to get rid of the last 1 in Col1 and of the .0 in Col2.

I could not manage to do it. I appreciat any help.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use splitting values by `.` and selecting first lists by `str[0]` indexing:

```
df['ColNew'] = (df['Col1'].str.rsplit('.', n=1).str[0]  + '.' + 
                df['Col2'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[0])
print (df)
          Col1     Col2           ColNew
0  11.50.199.1  12121.0  11.50.199.12121
1  12.55.222.1  12121.0  12.55.222.12121
```

Or use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for last digits with `.` in both columns:

```
df['ColNew'] = (df['Col1'].str.replace(r'\.\d+$', '')   + '.' + 
                df['Col2'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\.\d+$', '') )
```

Comment: Thanks. Both work fine. Do you also get a red warming when you run the code? Pandas recommends me: `Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: using `rsplit` is nice

Comment: @Gobrel Is some filtration before my solution? if yes, then use `copy` like `df =df[df.col >10].copy()`

Answer (score 1):

Using an apply :

```py
df["ColNew"] = df.apply(lambda s:
                        s.Col1.str.removesuffix("1)"
                        + s.Col2.str.removesuffix(".0"),
                        axis=1)
```

We use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to iterate on the DataFrame. Here we want to iterate on rows because we have to retrieve a value from 2 different columns, so we specify `axis=1`.

Since `apply` passes a `Series` to the function, we access the corresponding column's values using `s.col_name` (or s["col_name"]).

We then use [.str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html?highlight=series%20str#pandas.Series.str) to vectorize our string operation : [removesuffix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix), which will return the string passed, minus the provided suffix.

Note that `.str` will fail if the Series' type is not already string. In that case we need to convert it to string explicitly before using `.str` using `.astype(str)` :

```py
df["ColNew"] = df.apply(lambda s:
                        s.Col1.astype(str).str.removesuffix("1)"
                        + s.Col2.astype(str).str.removesuffix(".0"),
                        axis=1)
```

Actually, if the trailing `.0` is because `Col2`'s dtype is `float`, then the simplest way to remove these is probably `Col2.astype(int).astype(str)`, an approach which should work for both answers if there is no nans in `Col2`.

If there are nans in the column, then `astype(int)` will fail and `astype('Int64')` won't do because `str(pd.NA)` yields `'<NA>'`, not an empty string, so working with strings from the start is best in that case.